# Java while-loop create text fields from string characters

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm currently working on text fields, and I'm using *NetBeans* with Java. The assignment requires a user to enter a sentence. The program reads the sentence, and displays a frame with the sentence that the user entered, but with each character in its own text field. Below is my code along with some comments that point out where I'm getting errors.

```
package lab.pkg2.pkg2;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Lab22 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // initialize string 
        String str1;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // scanner reads string
        System.out.print("Enter a sentence");
        str1 = sc.next();
        System.out.println(str1);

        // Create frame 
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Characters in Text field :");
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // Create a text field with a single character
        While(str1 == length) { // error
            JTextField tf = new JTextField(4);
            System.out.print(str1.length());

            String ch = str1;
            tf.setText(String.valueOf(ch));

            str1++; // error
        }

        String ch = str1;
        frame.add(tf); // error

        // make another text field with a single character
        // Set up the frame and displays it
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the *errors* you are encountering. I just noticed the comments in your code which point out the errors, it might be a good idea to also include a summary/list of errors after the code block.

Answer (score 3):

#### `While(str1 == length)` Explanation:

There are multiple reasons why the line `While(str1 == length)` results in errors.

1. `While` is not the correct syntax, `while` with a lowercase `w` is the correct syntax.
2. `str1` is a `String`, `String` is an `Object`, when checking for equality of objects through the operator `==`, the references (locations in memory) are checked, not the contents of the objects. To check for equality between objects use the `.equals()` method.
    **Note:** Using the `==` operator between objects will not result in a compilation error. But if used to check for object equality then it will result in a logical error, which is usually way worse than a compilation error.
3. You never declared a variable `length`, I'm assuming you meant to write the loop's condition to resemble `while(str1.length() != 0)`. If you did mean to write `while(str1 == length)`, assuming `length` is an `int`, it does not make since to compare an object (`String`) to a primitive (`int`) and it's not allowed.

#### `str1++` Explanation:

The reason `str1++;` results in error is similar to the second point above. `str1` is a `String` which is an `Object`. Most primitives (`int`, `float`, `double`, ...) have `+, -, *, /, ++, --, ** ...` operators, but most objects don't, with the exception of a few like `Iterator`s, and the objects that do are set in stone. Languages like C++ allow you to overload operators but Java does not. Thus, `str1++` does not work, you have to use the methods supplied by the `String` class to alter the contents of `str1`.

#### `frame.add(tf)` Explanation:

The reason `frame.add(tf)` results in error is because `tf` is no longer in scope. `tf` was declared inside the `while` loop, anything declared inside curly braces (`{ }`) cannot be referenced outside of the curly braces. If you need to alter a variable within curly braces and then use it outside of curly braces, then declare it before the curly braces.

#### Future Logical Error:

> The assignment requires a user to enter a sentence.

If the words in the sentence are separated by spaces then you're going to wonder why only the first word in the sentence is being *processed*. The reason lies in the difference between the `next` and `nextLine` methods of the `Scanner` class. `next` reads until a specified delimiter is encountered (space by default), `nextLine` reads until the operating system's new-line character is encountered. Thus you're going to want to use:

```
str1 = sc.nextLine();
```

Here's a good StackOverflow question with answers, in case you run into any trouble while using the `Scanner` class' `next` methods: [Skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)

#### Side Note:

You can use a `while` loop to achieve the desired results, but a `for` loop is much easier to implement in this situation. If you use a `for` loop then you won't have to truncate `str1` on every iteration. A `for` loop example:

```
// create text fields with a single character
for(int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
    JTextField tf = new JTextField(4);
    char ch = str1.charAt(i);
    
    // set the newly created text fields text to ch
    tf.setText(ch + "");
    
    // add the text field to frame while it's still in scope
    frame.add(tf);
}
```

However, if you have to use a `while` loop then something similar to the following will work:

```
// create text fields with a single character
while(str1.length() != 0) {
    JTextField tf = new JTextField(4);
    char ch = str1.charAt(0);
    
    // chop off first (zeroeth) character from str1
    // unless it's the last character
    str1 = (str1.length() > 1) ? str1.substring(1) : "";
    
    // set the newly created text fields text to ch
    tf.setText(ch + "");
    
    // add the text field to frame while it's still in scope
    frame.add(tf);
}
```

#### Working `main` Method Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // initialize string 
    String str1;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // scanner reads string
    System.out.print("Enter a sentence");
    str1 = sc.next();
    
    System.out.println(str1);

    // create and set up frame 
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Characters in Text field :");
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    // create text fields with a single character
    for(int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
        JTextField tf = new JTextField(4);
        char ch = str1.charAt(i);
        
        // output the character for debugging?
        System.out.println(ch);
        
        // set the newly created text fields text to ch
        tf.setText(ch + "");
        
        // add the text field to frame while it's still in scope
        frame.add(tf);
    }
    
    // let frame's layout manager do it's thing
    frame.pack();
    // show the frame
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```